# Image loading with Picaso Android library

Tags: android, picasso

I want to use Picasso Android library in my project to load image.
According to Picasso doc, This line of code should display the image

```
ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Picasso.with(this).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView1);
```

And in layout,

But for myself, I could not manage to work that.
Anybody please let me know what is missing in my code.

Thanks.
Ruhul

Comment: did you get error in logcat? did you get airplane mode or something like that in logcat?

Comment: The code looks fine to me, i also use Picasso in my own project.
Do you have an imageview in your activity/fragment xml named "imageView1" ?
Do you get any kind of error messages in the logcat?

Comment: Hello Rahul, I am having the same issue. Have you solved this issue. Please share the solution. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah,  I have imageView1 in Layout.xml.
The problem is solved by adding the below lines in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Thanks.
--Ruhul

Answer (score -1):

Now I want to get the resource ID of my dynamically loaded like this

```
private static int[] images = { R.drawable.nature_1, R.drawable.nature_2, R.drawable.nature_3, R.drawable.nature_4, R.drawable.nature_5 };
```

Thanks.